# Using rxjs finalize

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have the following rxjs stream:

```
this.universities$ = this.activatedRoute.queryParams.pipe(
        switchMap((obj: any) => this.httpService.getUniversitiesList(this.numberOfRows, new URLSearchParams(obj).toString()).pipe(
          tap((res: any) => {
  
            this.totalPages = res.pagination.total;

            
            if ((res.pagination.current_page > 1)){
              setTimeout(() => this.paginator.changePage(res.pagination.current_page - 1));
            }

          })
        ).pipe(
          startWith(null)
        ))
      );
```

At the moment I have that rather ugly `setTimeout` which sets PrimeNG's paginator number. Without it, I'd be trying to set it before the data is ready and therefore the number won't be set.

From what I've read I need to use the rxjs operator `finalize` to do this properly. But I'm unsure where to place that. Do I need to pipe and switchMap after the tap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer seems to work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73581414/4711754) using the first property for the primeng paginator. [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pblnvn?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

I've split the getting of total pages and first into separate streams. Using `share()` prevents hitting api twice.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <p-paginator
    [rows]="pageSize"
    [totalRecords]="totalPages$ | async"
    [first]="first$ | async"
    >
  </p-paginator>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  totalPages$: Observable<number> = of();
  pageSize = 10;
  first$: Observable<number> = of();

  ngOnInit() {
    const data$ = mockGetUniversitiesList().pipe(
      tap((res) => console.log(`Got data...${JSON.stringify(res)}`)),
      share()
    );

    // get total pages
    this.totalPages$ = data$.pipe(map((res) => res.pagination.total));

    // change page
    this.first$ = data$
      .pipe(
        map((res) => res.pagination.current_page - 1),
        filter((page) => page > 1),
        map(page =>  page * this.pageSize)
      )
  }
}
```

Note I don't use primeng so answer may need adapting

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use tap logic in place where are you subscribing to `this.universities$`, since this.universities$ is a observable of universities data and only, and shouldn't have any another side-effects

I would suggest to do it in this way

```
this.universities$.subscribe(() => {
  this.resetPagination();
});
```

It might not fix your problem but code style will be more correct